# Upgrading pycharm venv python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-venv

I have python 3.6 in my venv on PyCharm. However, I want to change that to Python 3.8. I have already installed 3.8, so how do I change my venv python version?

I am on windows 10.

Changing the version on the project intepreter settings seems to run using the new venv not my existing venv with all the packages I have installed. Attempting to add a new intepreter also results in the "OK" button being greyed out, possibly due to the current venv being not empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a new virtual environment with the interpreter which version is 3.8.

1. Go to Settings => Project => Python Interpreter

[image]

2. Click on the vertical 3 dots, and click on "Add".

[image]

3. Select Virtualenv Environment => New Environment

[image]

4. Choose as base interpreter the one which version is 3.8 (the one you just installed)

[image]

5. Click on "OK" => "OK"
6. Once you have set the new interpreter, PyCharm will warn you that you need update some dependencies based on your `requirements.txt` file or, in this case, `Pipfile.lock` (I am using `pipenv` for this project)

[image]

That's it!

Comment: Kind of a dumb question, but Pycharm says I need an empty environnement location. I can do that just fine, but I want to overwrite my old python version for the current environnement location with the newest version, can this be done? I want to do this because I have my own scripts in the old environnement location and having to create a new location would mean that I would need to copy paste my scripts from the old location to the new one, which doesn't seem right. Any thoughts on this? Thank you.

Comment: @MorningGlory did you manage to sort this out?

Comment: Blow away (or backup) your old venv, then try this.

Answer (score 1):

In pycharm you can do further steps:

1. Go in File-->Settings-->Python Interpreter
2. Select different python environment if already available from the drop down, If not click on "Add".
3. Select New Environment option, then in Base interpreter you can select 3.8 version

Comment: "OK" button is greyed out probably because venv is not empty

Comment: You can create a blank folder to create a virtual environment in that folder